# MonoDevelop Error - System.DllNotFoundException: libclntsh.so

Tags: oracle11g, mono, monodevelop, redhat, oracleclient

I have created a C# console project using Visual Studio 2008 and OracleClient (OCI) libraries to connect to a Oracle 11g database. This code works in Windows.  I copied the whole project into Linux and Open the solution using MonoDevelop 4.2.3.  But while running the project, the Database Open call throws an exception

```
    string connectionString = "Data Source=Test; User ID=UID; Password=PWD"
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    conn.Open();
```

Exception:

> System.DllNotFoundException: libclntsh.so   at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native)
>   System.Data.OracleClient.Oci.OciCalls/OciNativeCalls:OCIEnvCreate

The libclntsh.so file is under the location /home/dbuser/instantclient_12_1

I have set the environment variable by adding the below in the **/home/dbuser/.bashrc** file and rebooted the system.

> export
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/dbuser/instantclient_12_1:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

But still I am getting the same error. I couldn't find any option to include the Libraries in the MonoDevelop.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by doing the following

> echo $ORACLE_HOME/lib > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/dbconf.conf
>
> set the$ORACLE_HOME, $ORACLE_INCLUDE_PATH and $ORACLE_LIB_PATH to
>   /etc/profile.d

Because of some reason MonoDevelop IDE is not picking the library libclntsh.so if I use the OCI client libraries

Answer (score 0):

Looks like LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable is not set up correctly or does not get applied.

Try creating additional linker configuration file instead with the following command:

```
echo /home/dbuser/instantclient_12_1 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/instantclient.conf
```

Then as root update linker cache with command:

```
ldconfig
```

Restart MonoDevelop and try again.

Comment: I removed the envrionment variables from the file .bashrc and tried your code, still I am getting the same error.